# Displaying a TIFF file in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, geotiff-tiff

I'm completely new to OpenLayers and working with the map. I need to apply a layer from a TIFF file to the map in the OpenLayers library and I'm having difficulties.

I am displaying an OpenStreetMap map and trying to add a layer with a TIFF file, but I do not have a TIFF layer displayed.

```
const map = ref<Map>();

function createMainMapLayer() {
  const layer = new TileLayer({
    source: new XYZ({
      url: 'https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
    }),
    className: 'main-map',
  });
  return layer;
}

function createMapView() {
  const view = new View({
    center: fromLonLat([13.404954, 52.520008]),
    zoom: 5,
    maxZoom: 20,
  });
  return view;
}

onMounted(() => {
  map.value = new Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [createMainMapLayer()],
    view: createMapView(),
    controls: defaultControls({ attribution: false, zoom: false }),
  });
});

const source = new GeoTIFF({
  sources: [
    {
      url: '../../../public/assets/COPERNIC.tif',
    },
  ],
});

const layer = new TileLayer({
  source: source,
});

map.value?.addLayer(layer);
```

If I output a separate layer with a tif file, it is black and white, although it should be a heat map. QGIS recognizes 3 channels in this tiff file and shows the image correctly.

```
const source = new GeoTIFF({
  sources: [
    {
      url: '../../../public/assets/COPERNIC.tif',
    },
  ],
});

const layer = new TileLayer({
  source: source,
});

onMounted(() => {
  map.value = new Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [layer],
    view: new View({
      center: [-75.36865233762786, 0],
      zoom: 20,
    }),
  });
});
```

Can you tell me how this can be done?

Comment: As per the policy of this site, please ask one problem in one post.

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code of what has been tried so far, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code. Also limit your question to only one question.

Comment: The two views you use have very different centers.  Where should the file be, and what projection does it use?

Comment: @Mike 
The tif file displays a heat map of half the hemisphere of the world and has the format EPSG:4326. It was taken from Google Earth Engine. I have two such files and they form a heat map of the entire earth. I also wrote incorrectly earlier. tif has a single-channel gray image. I don't understand how to make it pseudo-colored.

Comment: Have you tried using the convertToRGB option in GeoTIFF?